# how to calculate machine cycle time of given micro controller unit

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on 8051 MCU from si labs. I want to generate exact 1ms delay using timer. For this I want to know what is the machine cycle time of a given MCU. The time taken by the MCU to complete one machine instruction. Then I can calculate how many machine cycles to complete 1ms delay.

Comment: You say that you want to use a timer, i.e. a peripheral for the special job of creating timings. But you ask about info for not using a timer, i.e. machine cycle of the MCU, i.e. something you only need for making a timing by looping with the CPU. Please explain more.

Comment: To use a timer, read about how to configure it, choose a timing, start it and use it to trigger code when the time has elapsed. You should have documentation on that. I guess you will have to learn about interrupt programming. The alternative is polling the timer, to detect when the timing has elapsed. That however is usually not how to use a timer.

Comment: You should probably migrate to newer Silabs parts like EFM32 families. 8051 has been dead for many decades. Writing C code for it will be almost as painful as using Simplicity Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a time delay by counting MCU cycles is a poor method - especially if you are coding in C where you have no control over the machine instructions the compiler will generate - your loop will likely change depending on compiler options such as optimisation level.

Moreover the MCU has no means of measuring its own clock; its only concept of time passing is in clock-cycle units - asking it how long a cycle is is rather like asking a human how long a second is.  The answer to the question of how long a clock-cycle is from the point of view of the MCU is always 1.

As the programmer of the system, it is your responsibility to know the clock speed.  Typically the hardware defines the speed by its crystal or oscillator rate, and the MCU PLL settings determine the multiplier.  Most often you will embed this speed as a constant in the start-up code; your code might access this constant.

Even then, you are better off creating delays using an on-chip timer unit rather than software-based instruction counting (and not all 8051 instructions are single cycle).  In that case, you still need to know the clock speed; then the timer clock may be further divided from that.

Comment: The determinism issue can be largely overcome (apart from interrupts) via inline assembly.  Such program delays are useful for short interstitial things, for example, bit-banging interfaces a little slower than the maximum rate that software could, or allowing a settling time between operations.

Comment: @ChrisStratton of course, but the question is tagged [C], and the time period 1ms, so ...

Answer (score 0):

To use the timer you need to know what is the frequency of the timer clock. Then you just need to : `timer_clocks=delay*frequency;`

Instruction timings you need to know only if you want blocking delay. There are two sources: uC documentation or experiment. To know how many loops you need just connect the oscilloscope to the pin and loop as many times as needed to archive the required impulse length